# Google Analytics Avg. Session duration is 00:00:00

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-analytics, analytics

I was finished my first app in which I was integrated Google Analytics v3 (easy to integrate for beginners, I think).

But there is a problem. All my stats about session duration is 00:00:01 or 00:00:00...but I using app sure for about 3 minutes.

I have ActivityStart(this); in onCreate and ActivityStop(this); in onDestroy, because my app come without onStop method in MainGame.java. Also there is only one activity (MainGame.java) because all game functions are written there.

What can be wrong with my code? Can I must create onStop method and put analytics stop code there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session duration is calculated based on the time between the first and the last interactive hit attributed to the session. If your app send only hits when the Activity starts your session duration will appear to be 0. To accurately measure the session real time clock duration you need to send a interactive hit when your activity is stopped. onDestroy call is not guaranteed to be called by Android ([Activity.onDestroy() reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy)) and therefor using it to mark the session end will not result in reliable session time reporting.